# Wildfly10: Dynamically configuration of an in-server EJB lookup. (add a EJBReceiver for remote server-to-server EJB invocations)

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, wildfly, wildfly-10

It is possible to configure dynamically an in-server ClientContext (server-to-server EJB invocations) in order to add remoting ejb receiver outbound connections?

Something like changing the `jboss-ejb-client.xml` configuration at runtime.

Initially I tried to configure the `InitialContext` with the `remote.connection.xxxx.host` properties. But the server simply ignores. Also ignores the `jboss-ejb-client.properties` file in classpath. After that, I tried to configure dynamically with `EJBClientContext.setSelector(someSelector)`, but apparently I can't due security reasons (SecurityException or so).